# Will new Foursquare changes (splitting Foursquare/Swarm) affect API?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, foursquare

This morning I saw that Foursquare is splitting its single service into 2 - one called Swarm and the other to retain the Foursquare name. I have looked on the Foursquare developer blog and have not seen any news about this change (yet), so I wanted to ask: Is this going to affect the API? If so, when can we hope to hear something about the changes?

Comment: Just saw this...http://engineering.foursquare.com/2014/05/01/what-todays-announcement-means-for-developers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our [blog post](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2014/05/01/what-todays-announcement-means-for-developers/) yesterday addresses this. We never make any major changes to the API without announcing it way in advance first to give developer proper time to prepare. When we're ready to make such announcements (related to the unbundling or otherwise) you will know about it!

In the meantime, the best things to do are make sure you follow [@foursquareAPI](https://twitter.com/foursquareapi) and double check that the email address associated with your Foursquare app is up-to-date and monitored, since we also make announcements there.